# Why did Airbus skip a few numbers when developing the A380?

Tags: airbus-a380

So at the time the A350 didn't exist so I will list the aircraft not including the A350. So it goes A300, A310, A318, A319, A320, A320, A321, A330, A340 then it skips to the A380. So why did Airbus skip a few numbers?

Comment: A little punctuation goes a long way, especially after commas. :)

Comment: because airbus want largest airliner have larger number, not to be the case of b747&b757

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question of aircraft name variants [have already been discussed](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/where-do-airplane-variant-numbers-come-from), but I just want to add that other reasons have also been proposed:

- The '8' in the 380 resembles the double decker configuration of A380.
- It was named A380 [because it is twice the size of A340](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AAirbus_A380/Archive_4)
- And of course, it is the lucky number for Chinese.

Comment: I don't know if this has been a reason for the A380, but many vehicle models are now named using "8" because China is expected to be *the* big market. The previous market (Occident) was more fond of the "7" found in Boeing models.